# During image update other images are returning empty except the one that I update

Tags: php, sql-update, image-upload

I've been trying a lot of different things to get the images to retain when other images are getting updated. Everything is good just except when I upload or update one of the images the other images are getting deleted or saved empty into the database.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
session_start();
    include ("connection.php");
    include ("functions.php");
    $user_data = check_login($con);

if(count($_POST)>0) {

if(!empty($_FILES['garden_photo1']['name'] . $_FILES['garden_photo2']['name']) && isset($_FILES["garden_photo1"]["name"], $_FILES['garden_photo2']['name'] )){

$id =  $_POST['id'];
$cultivar_name = $_POST['cultivar_name'];    
$breeder = $_POST['breeder'];
$lineage1 = $_POST['lineage1'];
$garden_photo1 = $_FILES['garden_photo1']['name'];
$ImageName = $_FILES['garden_photo1']['name'];
$ImageName2 = $_FILES['garden_photo2']['name'];
$target = "/cultivar/images/" . $ImageName;
$target2 = "/cultivar/images/" . $ImageName2;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['garden_photo1']['tmp_name'], $target);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['garden_photo2']['tmp_name'], $target2);
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE cultivar_db set  cultivar_name = ?, breeder = ?, lineage1 = ?, garden_photo1 = ?,  garden_photo2 = ?  WHERE id= ? ");
$stmt->bind_param( "sssssi",  $cultivar_name, $breeder, $lineage1, $garden_photo1, $garden_photo2, $id);
$stmt->execute();
  }else {
$id =  $_POST['id'];
$cultivar_name = $_POST['cultivar_name'];    
$breeder = $_POST['breeder'];
$lineage1 = $_POST['lineage1'];
$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE cultivar_db set  cultivar_name = ?, breeder = ?, lineage1 = ?  WHERE id= ? ");
$stmt->bind_param( "sssi",  $cultivar_name, $breeder, $lineage1,  $id);
$stmt->execute();
  }
$message = "Cultivar Record Modified Successfully!";
}



$id =  $_GET['id'];   
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cultivar_db WHERE id=?"; 
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

?>
```

---

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update Cultivar Data</title>
<style>
.success{color: green; font-size:20px; fonte-weight:bold;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="cultivar_db" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">


<div style="padding-bottom:5px;">
<p><a href="cultivar-database.php">Go Back to Cultivar Database </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit <?php echo $row["cultivar_name"];?>  Page</p>
</div>
 <br>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >
<br>
Cultivar Name: <br>
<input  name="cultivar_name"  value="<?php echo $row['cultivar_name']; ?>">
<br>
Breeder: <br>
<input type="text" name="breeder" value="<?php echo $row['breeder']; ?>">
<br>
Lineage 1 :<br>
<input type="text" name="lineage1"  value="<?php echo $row['lineage1']; ?>">
<br>
Garden Photo 1: <img id="output" src="../cultivar/images/<?php echo $row["garden_photo1"];?>" style="height:auto; width:70px;">
<br>
<br>
<input id="garden_photo1" type="file" name="garden_photo1"  >

<br>
Garden Photo 1: <img id="output" src="../cultivar/images/<?php echo $row["garden_photo2"];?>" style="height:auto; width:70px;">
<br>
<br>
<input id="garden_photo1" type="file" name="garden_photo2" >

<br>
<br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" >
<br>
<br>
<div class="success">
<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; } ?>
</div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of letting your code act as if it was a given, that there will always be a file uploaded for _all_ images - _check_ which ones you actually got an upload for, and update only those.

Comment: It's an update so you mean like if make it act like there's always a value for it. But my issue is when I update the existing image the other existing images are returning empty. I thought I can make my else right but it didn't work.

Comment: Right now, you appear to be only differentiating between the two cases, no images were uploaded at all - or two images were uploaded. You need to handle the case(s) that either one of the images was uploaded, while the other one wasn't, as well. But instead of writing different branches for all four possible combinations, it would make more sense if you handled each image upload separately. Was image 1 uploaded? Then process that upload, and update the column for image 1 in your database. Was image 2 uploaded? Then process that upload, and update the column for image 2 in your database.

Comment: So you mean if empty & isset image 1 process it first then next is  the image2 then process it and? Then if both images are being updated process it as well? Did I understand you right?

Comment: Process image 1, if it was uploaded. Process image 2, if it was uploaded. No need to handle the case "both were uploaded" separately any more after that.

Comment: Ok I think I got what you are saying I'll try it now.. thanks for the effort of helping a noob.

Comment: @CBroe it works. Thank you so much If you can add your answer ill accept it.Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, you appear to be only differentiating between the two cases, no images were uploaded at all - or two images were uploaded. You need to handle the case(s) that either one of the images was uploaded, while the other one wasn't, as well.

But instead of writing different branches for all *four* possible combinations (no image was uploaded; image 1 was uploaded but image 2 was not; image 1 was not uploaded but image 2 was; or both were uploaded), it would make more sense if you handled each image upload separately:

Was image 1 uploaded? Then process that upload, and update the column for image 1 in your database.

Was image 2 uploaded? Then process that upload, and update the column for image 2 in your database.

Comment: any idea about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73229004/update-multiple-ids-values