# Update Multiple ids values

Tags: php, sql-update

I've been trying ot figure out how can I update multiple id's with multiple values in one form while fetching it. I'm not getting any error but its not updating on my database.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
session_start();
    include ("connection.php");
    include ("functions.php");

    $user_data = check_login($con);


if(count($_POST)>0) {
if (isset($id, $qty_clones, $qty_teens, $qty_mother, $qty_autoflower_seeds, $qty_feminized_seeds, $qty_naturalprogeny_seeds, $qty_quick_seeds )){
    
$id = $_POST['id'];
$qty_clones = $_POST['qty_clones'];
$qty_teens = $_POST['qty_teens'];
$qty_mother = $_POST['qty_mother'];
$qty_autoflower_seeds = $_POST['qty_autoflower_seeds'];
$qty_feminized_seeds = $_POST['qty_feminized_seeds'];
$qty_naturalprogeny_seeds = $_POST['qty_naturalprogeny_seeds'];
$qty_quick_seeds = $_POST['qty_quick_seeds'];   

$stmt = $con->prepare("UPDATE cultivar_db set qty_clones = ?, qty_teens = ?, qty_mother = ?, qty_autoflower_seeds = ?, qty_feminized_seeds = ?, qty_naturalprogeny_seeds =?, qty_quick_seeds =?, qty_hemp_seeds = ? WHERE id IN(1,4,8,10) ");
$stmt->bind_param( "iiiiiiiii", $qty_clones, $qty_teens, $qty_mother, $qty_autoflower_seeds, $qty_feminized_seeds, $qty_naturalprogeny_seeds, $qty_quick_seeds, $qty_hemp_seeds,  $id);
$stmt->execute();
  } 
}

  $id =  $_GET['id']=[1,4,8,10];   
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM cultivar_db WHERE id = ?  IN (1,4,8,10) "; 
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql); 
  $stmt->bind_param( "i", $id);
  $stmt->execute();
  $result = $stmt->get_result(); 
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


?>
```

---

```
<form name="cultivar_db" method="post">
    
<?php
 $result1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM cultivar_db  ");
if (mysqli_num_rows($result1) > 0) {

?>

    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >



<table>
    <tr>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Cultivar Name</th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Action</th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Clones </th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Teens </th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Mother </th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Auto Flower Seeds</th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Feminized Seeds</th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Natural Progeny Seeds</th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Quick Seeds</th>
    <th id="cultivarheader">Qty Hemp Seeds</th>


</tr>

<?php
            $i=0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) {
            ?>

            <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["cultivar_name"]; ?></td>
        <td><button><a href="update-process.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">Update Page</a></button> <button><a href="/cultivar/<?php echo $row['url']; ?>">View Page</a></button></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_clones" value="<?php echo $row['qty_clones']; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_teens" value="<?php echo $row["qty_teens"]; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_mother" value="<?php echo $row["qty_mother"]; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_autoflower_seeds" value="<?php echo $row["qty_autoflower_seeds"]; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_feminized_seeds" value="<?php echo $row["qty_feminized_seeds"]; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_naturalprogeny_seeds" value="<?php echo $row['qty_naturalprogeny_seeds']; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_quick_seeds" value="<?php echo $row['qty_quick_seeds']; ?>" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty_hemp" value="<?php echo $row['qty_hemp_seeds']; ?>" ></td>
        
      </tr>
      <?php $i++; } ?>
</table>
 <?php } else {echo "No result found";}

?>
<button class="submitme" type="submit" name="submit"></button>

</form>
```

Comment: Multiple GET/POST parameters of the same name, get overwritten by PHP - unless you use square bracket "syntax" in your field names - `name="foo[]"`

Comment: that didn't work. I feel like im missing something. any suggestion or what do you think im doing wrong.

Comment: You will get arrays in $_POST for those fields now, so you need to loop over the data to update records one by one. If you are unsure what you are getting, start with a print_r or var_dump of $_POST.

Comment: im getting an empty array() on post.

Comment: Did you actually submit the form? If you dump it on the initial _GET_ request that is used to load the form in the first place, of course $_POST will be empty.

Comment: @CBroe so when i submit the form im seeing all arrays and also the one i change but for some reason the inputs are not updating.. what do you think is the proper way I can get them to update?

Comment: As said, you will get _arrays_ now in $_POST, so you should loop over them to perform your update statements.

Comment: seems like I can't make it loop right. i've been dealing with this for days now ;(. I definitely doing something wrong on it or i feel like im just missing a things or some silly thing on it.

Comment: @CBroe foreach ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['id']); $i++){. do you mean on looping on my case i should use multple of this for each name?. i've been trying to use foreach. I must've misunderstood this looping because I'm really not getting it to my database. array works i can see the changes but its not submitting what am i doing wrong? any suggestion or anything please thanks.

Comment: First of all, did you put `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" >` _inside_ your loop (and modify the name)? If you still only have one of those _before_ the whole table, then of course it won't work.
And then, you'll need to access `$_POST['id'][$i]`, `$_POST['qty_clones'][$i]`, etc. inside your loop.

Comment: yes on the input type hidden id , I did put my [$i] on all of it. I can still see all array it is updating but not going to database still. i tried just a single id and it works but when i added multiple i'm not going through

Comment: @CBroe I still can't get it to loop and updated on my database. i tried to make all possible answers here in stackoverflow. any help are much appreciated. I did make a temporary update button needs to get click to change url id then pull it out from there. I'm succesful but I want to edit the entire table of all at the same time. :( help